# when updation occurs new password get inserted and authentication fails (in mean stack application)

Tags: mongodb, passwords, mean-stack, bcrypt

password saved on db (when user registered) changes when user update his/her details.I have done below code for updation in routes/api.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.put('/profileupdation2/:ssn/:firstname/:lastname/:username/:email/:age/:phno',function(req,res) {
        var ssn1 = req.params.ssn;
        var fname = req.params.firstname;
        var lname = req.params.lastname;
        var username = req.params.username;
        var email1 = req.params.email;
        var age1 = req.params.age;
        var phno1 = req.params.phno;
        User.findOne({ssn:ssn1}, function(err,user) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
            if(!user){
                console.log('No user found');
            } else {
                user.ssn = ssn1;
                user.firstname = fname;
                user.lastname = lname;
                user.username = username;
                user.email = email1;
                user.age = age1;
                user.phno = phno1;
                user.update(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('updated!!!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return router; //returns the router object to server
};
```

Comment: Do not post code as image. People cannot copy an image to test the code on their own to see what may be the problem. Please read the FAQ on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok,tried to copy code but error in posting here

Comment: Please see [the Formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to post code

Comment: [Check This](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd), this will not solve your problem but it will help you to write RESTApis.

Comment: Thank you @AnkitKumar.I have got its solution.we just need to add code below while saving and before bcrypting ..

if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();//Changes password only when user changes it